# "Sparql filter by number of objects return for a given predicate

Tags: sparql

In the following query I'm trying to get a list of all entries ?s that include more than 3 objects for the predicate sctap:mentionedBy. However, I keep getting a malformed query error for this search. Does anyone see anything wrong with my query?

Thanks

```
SELECT ?s
WHERE {
    ?s sctap:mentionedBy ?o 
    FILTER (count(?o) > 3) 
}
```

The sparql error says: "Aggregate expression not legal". I'm not sure what that means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does anyone see anything wrong with my query?

Sure.  Just like the error message says, you're using an aggregate expression (`count(?o)`) where one isn't legal.  You can see in the table of contents of [SPARQL 1.1 Query Language](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/) what things are filter functions that you can use in a filter, and what things are aggregates, and where you can use each.  You can also try parsing queries at [sparql.org's query validator](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html).  For your query, it will give you the line and column numbers where something went wrong.  It's at `count(?o)`.

In this case, you're trying to count the number of **?o** values *for each* **s**, which means that you need to **group by ?s**, and that your filter will need to be father out.  E.g.,

```
select ?s where {
  ?s sctap:mentionedBy ?o
}
group by ?s
having (count(?o) > 3)
```

It's unlikely to  make a difference in this case, but you probably only want to count *distinct* values of **?o**, so you could also consider:

```
select ?s where {
  ?s sctap:mentionedBy ?o
}
group by ?s
having (count(distinct ?o) > 3)
```